# HTML/Javascript system for many different popups and widgets in the same page

Tags: javascript, css, html, modularity

I'm making a HTML5 page (game) which uses lot of popups and all kind of widgets appearing and dissapearing in the same page.

To implement this I could

- Have all the popups and widgets listed in the page, invisible (like lot of examples I saw), and keep toggling only visibility.
- Add and remove dynamically, using Javascript. I could put each popup as HTML fragment in a separate file (?).

The seconds is "modular" and I like the fact that I have no elements in the page which I'm not acutally using. But I don't know about performance (load HTML each time, DOM insertiong, etc.).

Is there a prefered/standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about loading HTML from server, then obviously this won't be efficient.

I don't know what kind of game you are writing but I don't think there will be any visible difference in performance (except for loading data from server) unless you create like thousands popups per second (I doubt it). Let's be honest - your game isn't using like 4GB of memory. :) And if it is, then you're probably doing something wrong. And I do not think there is any standard way. It's more like how you feel it. :)

For example I always try to load every possible data from server with one request and store it on client-side, because most problems with performance is actually related to client-server communication. I also like the DOM to be clean, so in most cases I hold the (hidden) data in JavaScript, except for forms' hidden fields.

On the other hand, if I have for example blog with discussion and I load some additional data (for example user data, which is supposed to appear as a popup after click on the user's name) I tend to store it in DOM elements because it is easier (at least for me) to control it (I'm talking about jQuery and jQuery UI).

Note that it is possible that recreating popups may lead to memory leaks, but it is highly unlikely if you use some popular library like (for example) jQuery UI.